# How to dynamically add/remove test rule?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, rule

I've written a `TomcatRunner` [junit rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) and use it as a [`ClassRule`](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/ClassRule.html). That works fine. It starts tomcat befor the test class is executed and shuts it down afterwards.

Now i'd like to use the same integratoin unit test in an other scenario, where there's no need to start/stop tomcat because it's ok to assume that it's already running.

Is there a way to dynamically add/remove a rule depending on a system property or some other configuration information?

```
public class MyTest {

    /**
     * I'd like to add/remove this based on configuration values.
     */
    @ClassRule
    public static final TomcatRunner tomcatRunner = new TomcatRunner();

    @Test
    public void thatClientCallWorksAsExpected() throws Exception {
        // test code
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use the same integration unit test in an other scenario"? Do you want to use the same test code?

Comment: Yes. But it should not have the rule, since tomcat is alreday running.

Comment: Why not do a `System.getProperty("tomcat_running")` or similar in the `TomcatRunner`?

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing. But I'd prefer to have it not there at all if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own test runner. `@RunWith(YOUR_RUNNER.class)`
and override

```
public class YOUR_RUNNER extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
  @Override
  protected List<TestRule> getTestRules(Object target) {
    List<TestRule> rules = super.getTestRules(target);
    rules.add(new ExternalResource {
       public void before() {
         System.out.println("methodRuleBefore");
       }

       public void after() {
         System.out.println("methodRuleAfter");
       }
    });
    return rules;
  }
}
```